# Boostrap Col vs Webkit Column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am always having this issue and I always solved it using `webkit-columns`. But I wanna know if there is a better way to do it with **Bootstrap**.

4 boxes inside a grid.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>
```

This gives me the 4 boxes but the last box have more margin than the others. I want all of them to have the same margin, but 0 on the corners like the image:
--- EDIT FOR CLARIFY ---


For Clarify my question im gonna add this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dao1cnok/1/) you see the blue box ? i want to the red boxes start and end with the blue box, can you do that ? not add margin to the blue box, the blue box must be 100% and the other box must be aligned with the first and end of that box
Here i do what i want: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9wby4mqq/) but here im using -webkit-column just for show you, if you can do this with bootstrap that would be nice.

[image: Columns]

Comment: you will have to make your own css classes, because boostrap and foundation, has those margins and padding predefined. or you can override their properties. and it seems you forgot the div with class "row" for containing the column ones.

Comment: I eddited the row stuff, but not work if i create my classes how can i create the clases ? i tryed allot of stuff, but cannot add a margin always right execp on the last, i need something that work like webkit column.

Comment: Why not create a child `div` for each column and then customize their margins? Instead of messing with the `col` classes?

Comment: I don't really understand how "the last box have more margin than the others" Bootstrap: http://codeply.com/go/foPoeMjF9f _ UIkit works the same way: http://codeply.com/go/uEbZ293MmU

Comment: maybe my question is not 100% well check this js fiddlle https://jsfiddle.net/dao1cnok/1/ you see the blue box ? i want to the red boxes start and end with the blue box, can you do that ? not add margin to the blue box, the blue box must be 100% and the other box must be aligned with the first and end of that box, edditig answer

Comment: This really had nothing to do with Bootstrap or UIkit. You can customize the CSS with first-child/last-child selectors, or use another elements in your first row and give that a blue background.

Comment: i think boostrap grid idea gonna helpme, but not. thanks for yours answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im gonna share this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/dao1cnok/) I created. I hope it gets you somewhere.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 custom-col">
            <div class="child-div">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 custom-col">
            <div class="child-div">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 custom-col">
            <div class="child-div">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 custom-col">
            <div class="child-div">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col-sm-3.custom-col{
    height:250px;
    /* outline: 1px solid green; */
    padding: 5px;
}

.child-div{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I updated the fiddle. [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/dao1cnok/2/)

Comment: This is not why i ask becouse the last box on the right is not aligned to the end of the div it has 5px of padding, so if you have another box upper to this it will not being aligned i updated your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dao1cnok/1/

Comment: I am sorry but what do you mean `not aligned`?

Comment: updated your https://jsfiddle.net/dao1cnok/1/

Comment: Please see update. Is that what you mean?

Comment: You are getting the idea, but i want that with % padding and using bootstrap classes and custom classes

Comment: This is an important thing to point out. "Percentage" of what? Are you referring to the parent `div`?

Comment: Here's another one using percentage. https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/dao1cnok/2/ If you are going to use lets say `10%` for padding that would be the `10%` of the window itself so try to use smaller percentage.

Comment: this may work i think boostrap grid idea gonna helpme, but not. thanks for yours answers

Comment: If you cant accept it you can at least upvote it :D